# Class diagram composition with generalisation

Tags: oop, inheritance, uml, composition, class-diagram

I am trying to show here that Admin is a sub-class of User which is shown through the open triangle relationship connection. Is this enough to show that the sub-class relies on the main parent class to exist or would I then need to further apply composition? I have shown my example below. I am super confused regarding this. I feel it's enough to show it through the specialization arrow but I am not sure.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this enough to show that the sub-class relies on the main parent class to exist or would I then need to further apply composition?

Because of the generalization an *Admin* is a *User*, so if there is no *User* at all (`User.allInstances()->size() = 0`) then there is no *Admin* too. But of course you can have *User*(s) without having *Admin*.

If you just want to say that nothing more than the generalization is necessary.

But if you want to indicates an *Admin* is a *User* and there is 1 and only 1 admin you can do :

[image]

As you can see *admin* is a property of the class *User* (*isStatic* is true) because it is written underlined, no need to have it for all instances (including the admin(s)).

An other way to say the same without using an additional relation is :

[image]

Of course if you want to say there is at least one admin and not exactly one just use the multiplicity `1..*` in the first solution or modify the constraint to have `{allInstances()->size() >= 1}` in the second solution.

Comment: Ah okay. So it's enough to have just the generalisation which suggests that admin is a property of the class User, no need to further show this through composition?

Comment: I am trying to show that Admin is also a type of "User" which is why I used generalisation. I also want to show that without User there is no Admin since Admin is a user which is why I done composition to show that Admin relies on the existence of the class User. Not sure if this is correct or necessary to show through composition. Quite confused about this. Hope this makes sense. I will try to re-explain if it does not :D

Comment: Thanks for this, super helpful, really appreciate it. Is there anyway I could contact you to discuss Class diagrams further?

Comment: @ASH the best is to continue to use question on S.O., that also allow other people to have access to them

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add another view to [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196787/3723423)'s excellent and accurate answer regarding generalization.

Yes, it is indeed sufficient to make `Admin` a specializatrion of `User`:  this means that `Admin` is a `User`.  It also means that `Admin` inherits `User`'s non-private properties and operations (i.e. `AuthenticateUser()`).  Finally it means that an instance `a` of `Admin` is also an instance of `User` and has hence a `username` and a password, although these are visible only to `User` instances.  Unfortunately,  once an object created as `Admin`, it will always stay an `Admin`.

Your hesitation about composition is therefore perfectly understandable: it is often advised to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  You could perfectly imagine to have a `User` that has an `Admin` role, without `Admin` inheriting from `User`.  But this is a radically different design. And in this specific case, it would be strange, if there wouldn't be other roles as well.

Last but not the least, it's worth to mention de [decorator pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) that may combine inheritance with aggregation (instead of composition):  In this design, you would make `Admin` a decorator of `User`:  it extends the reponsibilities of the User with `Admin` responsibilities (i.e. with additional operations).  But this can be done at runtime:  you can create a `User`,  add an `Admin` responsibility, or remove the `Admin` responsibility.  THis is much more dynamic.

Comment: This was incredibly well explained. Thank you so much to you both!